# How to print the request when using HTTPie?

Tags: httpie

Is it possible to print on output the request (headers and body), in addition to the response, using HTTPie?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

> `--verbose`, `-v` Print the whole HTTP exchange (request and response).

If you want, you can print any combination of request headers, request body, response headers and response body independently.  See `--print`

https://github.com/jkbr/httpie#output-options